# Loading the partial file after fetching the data from ajax call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I am loading a partial file which fetches the data using a ajax call. The issue is the partial file gets loaded immediately once the link is clicked on the browser but the data will be populated after some delay inside the partial file template. Is there a way to load the partial file once the ajax request has returned the data. Also till the partial file gets loaded is there a way to show some spinner/progress bar on the ui?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-include='some expression'` and update the $scope.tmplateURL after the $ajax call.

### See an example [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/b2KNSTA6mb2S4Dznrw0I?p=preview).

Comment: I am loading the partials using `ng-view`tag in my main page. Can the sma method can be applied to ng-view also?

Comment: try to use `$route.current.templateUrl`